# How to make a form with the Post method and pass from it an Integer value to the controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to create a form that contains a single field of type Number and pass its value to the controller via the POST method.

UserController.java

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public String showUserProfile(@PathVariable final Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUserById(id));
    model.addAttribute("howMuchToIncrease", new Integer(0));
    return "user/user_item";
}

@PostMapping("/users/{id}/refill")
public String showButtonTopUpBalance(@PathVariable final Long id,
                                     @ModelAttribute("howMuchToIncrease") Integer howMuch) {
    userService.topUpBalance(id, howMuch);
    return "redirect:/users/" + id;
}
```

user/user_item.html

```
<form role="form" method="post" th:object="${howMuchToIncrease}"
  th:action="@{'/users/{id}/refill' (id=${user.id})}">
    <input type="number" th:field="${howMuchToIncrease}"/>
    <button type="submit">To Up Balance</button>
</form>
```

But right after I press the confirm button, it all ends with this error:

> Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.()
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.()

Comment: Which line caused the exception? and What is the type of user's id

Comment: @esprittn Signature of the second method, I think. Long type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:object` must reference a bean, and in your case it is a value. Values are not java beans.

Try the following:

I. Add a bean class:

```
public class IncreaseData {
    private int howMuchToIncrease = 0;

    public int getHowMuchToIncrease() {
        return howMuchToIncrease;
    }

    public void setHowMuchToIncrease(int howMuchToIncrease) {
        this.howMuchToIncrease = howMuchToIncrease;
    }
}
```

II. Use it instead of `Integer` instance:

```
model.addAttribute("increaseData", new IncreaseData());
```

and

```
public String showButtonTopUpBalance(@PathVariable final Long id,
                                     @ModelAttribute("increaseData") IncreaseData howMuch) {
```

III. And in your template:

```
<form role="form" method="post" th:object="${increaseData}"
  th:action="@{'/users/{id}/refill' (id=${user.id})}">
    <input type="number" th:field="*{howMuchToIncrease}"/>
    <button type="submit">To Up Balance</button>
</form>
```

(note the asterisk in `th:field`).